# How can i highlight the boxes if when i mouseover?

Tags: hyperlink, mouseover, highlight

Im just really new at this, i dont even know how to use CSS, anyway, this is the html that i want to fix, I WANT THE BOXES that has links in them to be highlighted or something when mouse is on it.

```
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-351" src="http://gms-wga.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/WGA-Organogram.jpg" alt="WGA Organogram" usemap="#wga" width="1126" height="1122" />

<map name="wga"> <area title="" alt="" coords="135,131,479,228" shape="rect" href="/about-us/program-implementation-structure/wga-coordinators-and-focal-points/" target="" /> <area title="" alt="" coords="152,299,457,415" shape="rect" href="/about-us/program-implementation-structure/wga-coordinators-and-focal-points/" target="" /> <area title="" alt="" coords="642,132,949,227" shape="rect" href="/about-us/program-implementation-structure/wga-co-chairdirector/" target="" /> <area title="" alt="" coords="662,303,911,394" shape="rect" href="/about-us/program-implementation-structure/adb-officer/" target="" /> <area title="" alt="" coords="290,512,837,742" shape="rect" href="/about-us/program-implementation-structure/wga-secretariat/" target="" /> </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't do it with just html. If you want interactivity like that you will have to learn Jquery. Our just javascript in order to do that. A good place to learn it is www.codeacademy.com/

Comment: oh no... >.< i guess i dont have a choice but to learn more... thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a background image and transparent `<div>` tags so that it will highlight when you hover? Only if you are okay with using them :)

Comment: Okay :) Let me know if you need further help or post the code once you have something :)